# Difference between service rights and user rights

Tags: powershell, session, service, permissions

I am having a hard time understanding the differences between what can be done with a service session vs with an user session.

To work on it, I have a simulated env with a windows machine. A service is launched by an user I made specifically for this context, user_svc. Said user obviously has the right to launch a session as a service.

now, said service can open a shell. The shell says that I am user_svc, however there are things that user_svc can do (if he were to open a session and a shell), that I cannot do in this specific shell. What bother me is that, technically, both shell are run as user_svc, why does it matter than one is launched by a service and not the other? What difference would it make?

I'm testing mostly with `query session` command:  when I execute it from the shell launched by the service, it show me either nothing (even though said shell itself should be a session?) or user_svc session if i have one connected on the machine. No other, even thought I have admin session connected.
However, if I open a session as user_svc on the machine, launch a powershell and do a `query session`, it does show me every connected session (even admin ones).

I've tried giving more rights to user_svc (mostly in local security strategy) so that the "service shell" would have the same behaviour than the "user shell", but it hasn't changed anything (this is a simulated env, no security issue here, but of course I wouldn't want to give too much right to the user). I've also tried other commands to see the differences; the command `get-wmiobject loggedonuser` has the same behaviour, where "service shell" can see only user_svc, while "user shell" can see every connected user.

I've made another test when the service is launched by local administrator; then, when the service run the shell and perform a query session, I do see all connected sessions, just like the local administrator can see them. So it looks like it's related to user rights, but since user_svc itself can run the command...I don't understand.